# How .NET 3.5 (lambdas, Linq) evolved

Tags: linq, .net-3.5, lambda, anonymous-types

I remember reading a post about a year or so ago by Scott Hanselman (maybe by scott guthrie) about how Linq evolved.  It remember it showing that anyonymous types led to lambda expressions which then led to Linq in some way.  I can't seem to find it on google.  Does anyone else remember this post?  If so, can you please post it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163400.aspx).  I found it by searching for "linq c# 3.0 features"

Answer (score 2):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163400.aspx